# How to make a script to rename images and videos with the date of modification?

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

I have a gallery folder with images and videos in it named in unwanted format.
I want to make a script that scans through each file in that directory and when it finds an image or a video to rename it in this format: "IMG_20190117_200445.jpg"
Year,Month,Day_Hour,Minute,Second.Extension
And the same with videos but with adding the video extension.
How can I do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `find` to traverse through the directories; `stat` to get the timestamp; `date` if you need to wrangle it to a different format; `mv` for renaming. If the files have some sort of structure in their names, you may be able to use `rename` to do a batch renaming operation.

Comment: As addition to previous comment: if you want to use image metadata for source of renaming - `imagemagic`. And `sed` plus `date` or `awk` to extract the date from metadata in text form.

Comment: @WhiteOwl Can you please give me the working line of code, to extract the date of modification from the metadata and make the file named as mentioned above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that I think would do what you ask.

I first define a function that takes an extension and a type (either "IMG" or "VID"), uses `find` to get all the regular files with that extension, loops over them, uses `stat` to determine their modification time, `date` to determine the new filename, and renames them.

The script applies the function first to various image extensions then various video extensions.

```
#!/bin/bash

# a function to rename all files with a given extension
# takes two arguments: the extension, plus either "IMG" or "VID"
rename_ext() {
    # read the arguments to the function
    local ext="$1"
    local ftype="$2"
    # loop over all files with that extension
    while IFS= read -r -d '' filename ; do
        # read the (sub)directory name
        dirname="$(dirname "$filename")"
        # find the modification time
        modifytime="$(stat -c '%Y' "$filename")"
        # determine the new name
        local formatted="$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S' -d @$modifytime)"
        local newname="${ftype}_${formatted}.${ext}"
        # rename the file (and report that we are doing it)
        echo renaming "$filename" to "$dirname/$newname"
        mv -n "$filename" "$dirname/$newname"
    done < <(find -iname "*.$ext" -type f -print0)
}

# run the function on various image extensions
for ext in apng avif bmp gif jpeg jpg png tif webp ; do
    rename_ext "$ext" "IMG"
done

# run the function on various video extensions
for ext in avchd avif avi flv m2ts m4v mkv mov mp4 mpeg mpg mpv mts ogv qt vob webm wmv ; do
    rename_ext "$ext" "VID"
done
```

You might want to try it once with the `mv` line commented out to make sure it's doing what you expect.

You might also consider using the exif metadata instead of the file modification time, but that's a little more involved.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It's perfect. Thanks a lot.